# kubernetes cronjob dont works correctly when values are customized

Tags: kubernetes, cron, rancher

I am using rancher 2.3.3
When I config cronjob with schedule values like @hourly and @daily, works fine.
but when I config it with values like "6 1 * * *" , doesn't work.

OS times are sync between all cluster nodes

My config file

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: samplename
  namespace: samplenamespace
spec:
  schedule: "6 1 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: samplename
              image: myimageaddress:1.0
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: when do you expect this specific job to be triggered?

Comment: It supposes to run at 01:06 AM every day. What is the current behaviour?

Comment: Does it work with something like "*/5 * * * *"? Have you correctly accounted for the fact that (hopefully) your servers are running in UTC?

Comment: @suren  I run it before scheduled time   . for exapmle 1:03 AM

Comment: @coderanger   it works correctly with this format

Answer (score 1):

I find the root cause
scheduler container has different timezone, so it run with a few hours delay